# Why Windows Live Spaces Fetch Image Through HTTPS?

Tags: http, image, https

I happens to find that, when a live space page is loaded, inline images are fetched by https protocol instead of http protocol.

This doesn't make sense. The text part of live space is not fetched by https, why images are fetched with https? I bet the https way to fetch image just make the page loaded slower.

Is there any special advantage to choose https over http in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prevents a warning from some browsers that :

```
'This page contains both secure and insecure items'.
```

It has the disadvantage of non-caching objects over HTTPS (at least by default in most browsers/proxies).  Still, suppressing a warning is probably a good thing.

Comment: But, the live space page is http, not https. It is not supposed to pop up the warning if have inline http image src.

Comment: I believe Chaos is right, insofar as there are cases where the hosting page is HTTPS. Why they don't conditionally switch the links to use plain HTTP-- I don't know.